# Unable to parse the JSON

Tags: android, json

I am beginner in android how to pass this JSON http://coinabul.com/api.php and show the USD item of all catageory in a text box on main activity and when i m showing the log usd value is showing 210 for three keys but in json it have three different value

```
protected void onPostExecute(InputStream result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    progress.dismiss();

    String response = ConvertStreamIntoString.convertStreamToString(result);

    Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> topDictionary = new Hashtable<String, Dictionary<String, String>>();
    Dictionary<String, String> innerDictionary = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsobject = new JSONObject(response);
        Iterator<String> iterator = jsobject.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            // String value = getString(jsobject, key);
            String v2=null;
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsobject.getJSONObject(key);
            Iterator<String> iterator123 = jsonObject.keys();
            while (iterator123.hasNext()) {
                String keysss = (String) iterator123.next();
                String value = getString(jsonObject, keysss);
               innerDictionary.put(keysss, value);
                Log.e("innerDict",innerDictionary.toString());
            }

            topDictionary.put(key, innerDictionary);
            Log.e("asd", topDictionary.toString());
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    context.showdata(topDictionary, innerDictionary);
}
```

Comment: If I will provide you a method to parse the JSON then it would resolve your issue?

Comment: @sUndeep ok  u can give me the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the method below. You just need to pass the response string inside. Please let me know if you find any problem:

```
private void parseResponse(String response) throws JSONException {
        Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> topDictionary = new Hashtable<String, Dictionary<String, String>>();


        JSONObject jsobject = new JSONObject(response);
        Iterator<String> iterator = jsobject.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();

            JSONObject jsonObject = jsobject.getJSONObject(key);
            Iterator<String> iterator123 = jsonObject.keys();
            Dictionary<String, String> innerDictionary = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            while (iterator123.hasNext()) {
                String keysss  = iterator123.next();
                String value = jsonObject.getString(keysss);
                innerDictionary.put(keysss, value);

            }
            topDictionary.put(key, innerDictionary);
        }
        Log.v("topDictionary",topDictionary.toString());             
        showdata(topDictionary);
    }

private void showdata(
            Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> topDictionary) {
        for (Enumeration e = topDictionary.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            String keyTop = e.nextElement().toString();
            Log.v("keyTop",""+keyTop);
            Dictionary<String, String> innerElements = topDictionary.get(keyTop);
            for (Enumeration ei = innerElements.keys(); ei.hasMoreElements();) {
                String keyInner = ei.nextElement().toString();
                String value = innerElements.get(keyInner);
                System.out.println("key: "+keyInner+" value:"+value);
                // Here you can show your values in textview
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: i got the whole data  i need to show the data on textview which is on main activity..of key name "USD"  ** i am passing the inner dictonary and outer dictonary**  and call the method showdata(topdictonary,innerdictonary)    and on main activity i write the  code   String s1= topDictionary.get(innerDictonary).get("USD")
  textView.setText(s1);
in that method then it is showing error plz solve it

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh Can you please mention whose USD value you want to display on textview 1st/2nd/3rd/all ?

Comment: all the usd value ...basically i want all the value which have title USD                 String s1= topDictionary.get("Silver").get("USD");
  String s2= topDictionary.get("Gold").get("USD");
  String s3= topDictionary.get("BTC").get("USD");
  
  String s4 = s1 + "\n" + s2 + "\n"+ s3 ;
  textView.setText(s4);    i m using such way but i dont want to mention the keys BTC, GOLD,SILVER every time

Comment: So do you want those text to be created & displayed dynamically?

Comment: no i want the how should i get all the keys of main dictionary and by that keys i get the sting atttached with USD key; something likethat                       'String s1= topDictionary.get(topdictonaryallkeys).get("USD") '   where topdictonary all keys include Silver, Gold and BTC..and many more if it have

Comment: See my edited code above having a method showdata. As the values having Dictionary/HashMap are dynamic in nature, so you have to either create dynamic textview or layout having textview for all i.e, USD,Ounce,Grams,SilverOunces,SilverGrams so that you can display the values on those textviews. Else there's no way to know how to show.Thanks